# Best way to get a value from Firebase inside cellForRowAtIndexPath?

Tags: firebase, swift3

I have the following Firebase structure:

- artists

  - artist1

    - name: artist 1
  - artist2

    - name: artist 2
- sets

  - set1

    - venueKey: venue1
    - artistKey: artist1
    - time: 1 Jan
  - set2

    - venueKey: venue1
    - artistKey: artist2
    - time: 1 Jan
  - set3

    - venueKey: venue2
    - artistKey: artist1
    - time: 2 Jan

In cellForRowAt I want to display each set's time and artist name. Currently I can display the set time and the artist's key:

```
public func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
 ...
 cell.setArtistLabel.text = set?.artistKey
...
}
```

How would I retrieve each artist's name from Firebase when populating a tableview?
Would I get all artists from Firebase on initialisation, store them in an array, and then use that to get their names? Or (hopefully not) do a check on Firebase for the artist's name every time cellforrow is called?

Answer (score 0):

Unless there is a distinct advantage to fetching each artist as a cell needs it (and I can't think of one) the first approach you mentioned (get all artists from Firebase on initialisation, store them in an array, and then use that to get their names) would be the way to go :)